# Ibn Ezra and R. Joseph Bonfils And different opinions on Judaism

Tags: torah-study, pentateuch-chumash, authorship, heresy, ikarim

Can I agree with them that some passages were not written by Moses and that in some parts there were updates to the type text in [Gen 14:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.14.14?lang=bi&aliyot=0) that is considered a sin in Judaism? I can agree with rabbis that it goes against some Maimonides precepts as it is seen the different opinions in Judaism and if I can agree with ancient rabbis in some respects and also if only I agree with some rabbis with different opinions

sorry for the silly question

Comment: I do not understand your question. There are those who say that the last verses in the Torah were written by Joshua after the death of Moses. However, others say they were written by Moses *in tears* as a prophecy. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @sabbahillel The question was on Daniel, not the Torah.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/anachronisms-in-the-torah/125832#comment414348_125832

Comment: @pcoz Based on the question Alex lined to, I think the OP meant "Gen[nesis] 14:14" (especially considering the book of Daniel, as we have it, only has 12 chapters). The "dan" part may have slipped in, as the verse Gen 14:14 mentions the place Dan (and that other question is based on Dan being mentioned there).

Comment: @TamirEvan Yes i think had a text update and some verses was not from moshe acordding to Ibn Ezra and make sense

Comment: The important point is not which human wrote the Torah, but that the Torah in its entirety was dictated by G-d. So Maimonides quotes the Sages that one who says Moses added to the Torah even one letter beyond G-d's dictation is a heretic. The debate over where Moses stopped and Joshua completed the Torah (if he did) and the opinion of the ibn Ezra all fall within this paradigm.

Comment: Genesis 14:14talks about the time of Abraham. What does this have to do with anyone saying that Moses did not write it under Hashem's dictation?

Comment: @sabbahillel Dan was at the time of joshua not moses Anachronism

Comment: @N.T. But update a city name does not add nothing of what G-d dictated remains the same

Comment: Could be Like  Tiqqun soferim ?

Comment: There are those that say that before the famine, the tribes had spread out into other areas of the land. Dan had started to settle in that area. Avraham saw with prophesy what would happen. In Egypt, the Children of Israel remembered this. Others say that Moshe used prophesy so that the people would know what was meant.

Comment: @MatheusSales We believe that there is an inherent holiness to the words of the Bible beyond their surface meaning, so one cannot "update" names. We also believe that the Bible was written with prophecy, so it is not surprising  for it to refer to future events.