# Textual Criticism of Nach

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, tanach, megillat-esther, biblical-criticism

I was recently learning Megillat Esther (as I prepare some shiurim on the topic), and was surprised to find the following comment by [Rabbi Moshe Yitzchak Ashkenazi (Tedeschi)](https://alhatorah.org/Commentators:R.%20Moshe%20Yitzchak%20Ashkenazi%20(Hoil%20Moshe)), in his commentary to [Esther 3:7](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Parshan/Hoil_Moshe/Esther/3.4#m7e2n6):

> ומחדש לחדש – חסרה כאן שיטה אחת שלימה ״ויפל הגורל בשלשה עשר לחדש״ והמעתיק שגה ברואה ועבר מן תיבת לחדש שבשיטה העליונה אל לחדש שבתחתונה.

> And from month to month - an entire line was omitted here: "and the lot fell on the 13th day of the month", and the copyist misread it, jumping from the word "lechodesh" on the upper line to the "lechodesh" on the lower line.

Rabbi Ashkenazi was a student of Shada"l, who was of the opinion that it is permissible to make textual emendations only in the books of Nevi'im and Ketuvim, but not the Torah (see footnote 62 [here](https://library.osu.edu/projects/hebrew-lexicon/03111-files/03111200.pdf)). I was nevertheless surprised by this comment because a) I am not aware of heavy criticism levelled against Rabbi Ashkenazi, whereas such criticism of Shadal is fairly well-known, b) because Hoil Moshe is found in more traditional places, such as on Hebrewbooks ([link](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/31889)), and c) because this strikes me as a more significant emendation, since it suggests that an entire line of the Megillah was missed.

So, my follow-up question(s):

Is it (halachically?/hashkafically?) permitted to suggest that the text of books in Nevi'im and Ketuvim is inaccurate? May one engage in textual criticism of these books, or is that considered inappropriate? Which (other) halachic authorities permit such a practice?

Note: This answer seeks Orthodox responses; I am aware of https://schechter.edu/is-it-permissible-to-study-biblical-criticism/

Comment: (Side-note: I have seen Ho'il Moshe write stuff like this in a number of places). Isn't it pashut that the text is inaccurate? Is that not what the Masoretes did, working hard to create a version that was accurate as possible, based on the tools they had at hand? See also [Bamidbar Rabbah 3:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bamidbar_Rabbah.3.13?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=en) on Ezra and the nekudot.

Comment: Just checking that you're specifically asking about textual (lower) criticism of Nakh, of which this is an example? And not historical (higher) criticism as well?

Comment: @Harel13 truth is, I remember seeing this in other places as well. I'm wondering about a) the difference between Torah and Nach in this regard and the halachic/hashkafic side of things (we read certain parts of Nach from scrolls, and are there any sources which say that the text of Nach is untouchable).

Comment: @JoelK correct. Higher criticism of Nach seems to be much more obviously problematic.

Comment: @רבות Not sure about your "more obviously problematic". It might be much easier to argue for source critical methods, since the gemara explicitly states that the books are edited, arranged, compiled.

Comment: In my experience, it is much more ingrained in people's minds that the Torah is "תורה מן השמיים" and therefore perfect from the bet of Beresheet to the lamed of Yisrael, which is,well...at least a little ignorant of what the MT *is*. Of course, that we have such a concept of תורה מן השמיים doesn't actually mean that the average Torah scroll is more perfect than the average Nach book or megillah.

Comment: He is at times willing to say that the text of the Torah was deliberately changed. E.g. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/anachronisms-in-the-torah/125832#125832

Comment: @magicker72 Edited/arranged/compiled is different than completely historically inaccurate, which is more of what I was thinking of when the term "historical criticism" was used. But I do agree with your basic point.

Comment: @Harel13 fair point, but there are definitely more robust methods in place to preserve the text of the Torah than there are for the Nach (at least for about 2000 years).

Comment: The reason why he isn't criticized is simply that no one heard of him. There are seforim such as Minchas Shai that responsibly use manuscripts to ascertain the correct texts. The chance that one sofer's mistake would throw off every single copy in the world is so minute as to be beneath consideration.

Comment: @n.t. not if the copy was early enough, and he would claim that it wasn't every copy in the world... But I agree that he was less well known.

Comment: @N.T. I'm not agreeing with his perspective, just explaining what I think he would say...

Comment: @N.T. Which sofer first wrote Dakah with a hei? To put it simply, every error began with one sofer's mistake, so that argument is beneath consideration.

Comment: @DoubleAA  There is a tremendous difference between one letter being off, and the sort of mistakes dealt with in Minchas Shai, and an entire phrase being missing.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות If the copy was in the days of Mordechai and Esther, don't you think they proofread the original copies and would have noticed if an entire phrase was missing? If it is later, after it was widely disseminated so everyone could read it, how could one sofer's mistake of such magnitude throw off every copy? This guy's argument makes no sense.

Comment: @N.T. if I could point you to a place in Minchat Shai where a longer phrase is debated, will you concede? (The formal logical problem with your argument is that while the chance of any particular copying corrupting the germline is indeed astoundingly small, the number of copyings performed over history is astoundingly big. Human are very bad at estimating if a very very large number times a very very small number is greater or less than one, as any precalc student knows.)

Comment: In terms of "permitted", I only know of 13 rules limiting belief. They include the Torah we have being the one Moshe compiled, which I guess we can extend to Yehoshua in Arvos Moav, given the dispute about who wrote the last pesuqim. But during the trip that was mostly through the Sinai. But no similar law from Nach.

Comment: IMHO Judaism has absolutely no problem with correcting sacred texts, we do find that sages in the Talmud quote non-existing versions of a verse, and Rashi replies "he had a different version". When you spellcheck a new scroll you might say to the scribe "you missed a letter", and that's fine.  This is not the criticism of the text but of a scribe.

Comment: @AlBerko that logic would apply to the Torah as well...

Comment: Oh, this is the beauty of Judaism, its flexibility and liveliness. Without this possibility, we would hit a wall and die, once we find a mistake we throw the whole thing. This approach is probably the reason for all kinds of literalist sects dying out at the beginning of the era and the free-thinking Pharisees taking their place. As a Baal Teshuva, I was stumbled also by this discrepancy some 20 years ago, until I understood that the dogmas you're taught are not factual, they are educational. They intend to enhance your faith rather than teach you facts.

Comment: The book of Ester was the only scroll totally missing in Qumran, it is missing holy names, and it appears to have a different status from other books. I suspect your extrapolation from Megilat Ester to all Nevi'im and Ketubim is unsupported.

Comment: @AlBerko a) I'm not sure what exactly you mean by the "educational dogmas" and "free-thinking Pharisees" - do you think that Chazal are ok with someone believing that there are mistakes in the Torah? b) You can find many examples where both these scholars engage in textual criticism of other books of Nach. Read through either of their commentaries for even a few perakim and you will doubtless come across a few examples.

Comment: @Micha https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17223/is-it-heresy-to-follow-secular-dating-on-the-destruction-of-the-first-temple/25998#comment38745_17223

Comment: a. Definitely, in my understanding, the Talmudic sages are OK with the unexactness of their [copies of the] scriptures. For ages, the Talmud was passed with misquotations, and it wasn't a big of a problem. The dogma of the exactness of the Torah is then purely "educational", it teaches us to respect and value the Torah, "as if" it was letter-tight.

Comment: @N.T. Agreed. In order for that to happen, you would have to be talking about the *sofer* who copied from the original manuscript written by Mordechai and Esther. And you would think that Mordechai and Esther would have noticed the mistake before it circulated round the world.

Comment: Rabbi Breuer might have discussed the subject in his book כתר ארם צובה והנוסח המקובל של המקרא. It's available on Otzar Hachochmah. I'd skim it for you, but I don't know when I'll have time.